# SQL Average Group By Include in Table

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, average

I have the following table

```
Type  Group     Price
1        A      600.00
2        A      800.00
3        B      300.00
4        B      300.00
5        B      400.00
6        A      200.00
```

I would like to show the Calculated Averages along Group  with Output as following using SQL Query.

```
Type  Group     Price          Average By Group
1        A      600.00             533.333
2        A      800.00             533.333
3        B      300.00             333.333
4        B      300.00             333.333
5        B      400.00             333.333
6        A      200.00             533.333
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this in SQL.

Comment: What database are you using? The answer might depend on system specific functionality so please tag the question with the relevant database.

Answer (score 0):

I am not always the best at making something efficient as possible and by looking at it I feel like there is a better way to do it but until then here is something that you should be able to work with...

```
 SELECT *, (SELECT AVG(Price) FROM averageTest t2 WHERE t2.[Group] = t.[Group] GROUP BY t2.[Group]) as GroupAverage FROM averageTest t
```

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support the ANSI standard window functions.  These exactly solve your problem:

```
select t.*,
       avg(price) over (partition by group) as average_by_group
from t;
```

Note:  `group` is a keyword in SQL, so it should not be used as a column name.  In general, it won't even be recognized unless it is escaped, using the appropriate escape characters for your database (typically double quotes work).